# Facing some errors on running 'Hello world' android app from Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I am building an first android app in Eclipse (Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)). I downloaded all Eclipse plugins along with AVD on system (Refer screenshot).

[image: ADV created]

When I ran below error occured 
**Failed to install HelloWorldAndriodApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
(null)
Launch canceled!**

I have gone through many link similar to this on google(incl. Stack Overflow) and also tried the solutions 1. Increased the ADB connection timeout to 500000
2. Clean build the application 3. Reset ADB
[image]
After all this exercise i started getting another exception 
**[2015-11-30 12:50:19 - HelloWorldAndriodApp] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2015-11-30 12:50:19 - HelloWorldAndriodApp] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2015-11-30 12:50:23 - HelloWorldAndriodApp] Launch canceled!**

Due to all these error my application is not initializing and see only black screen with 'Android' text in the middle of the screen of emulator.

Please suggest some solution to get rid of these errors.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.helloworldandriodapp"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >
        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

**Java Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.helloworldandriodapp.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:text="@string/hello_world"
      tools:context=".MainActivity" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="name">Type your name</string>
    <string name="app_name">HelloWorldAndriodApp</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
   <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
</resources>
```

**Log Cat:**

```
11-30 00:44:44.080: E/EGL_emulation(2502): Failed to establish connection with the host
11-30 00:44:44.180: E/(2502): Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
11-30 00:44:44.180: E/EGL_emulation(2502): Failed to establish connection with the host
11-30 00:44:44.200: E/(2502): Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
11-30 00:44:44.200: E/EGL_emulation(2502): Failed to establish connection with the host
11-30 00:44:44.220: E/(2502): Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
11-30 00:44:44.220: E/EGL_emulation(2502): Failed to establish connection with the host
11-30 00:44:44.220: E/(2502): Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
11-30 00:44:44.260: E/EGL_emulation(2502): Failed to establish connection with the host
11-30 00:45:26.580: E/PowerManagerService-JNI(2784): Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
11-30 00:45:57.330: E/memtrack(2804): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-30 00:45:57.330: E/android.os.Debug(2804): failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-30 00:46:12.840: E/SurfaceFlinger(55): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```

Comment: Post your code. And it would be easier to understand if your put your log cat exception details.

Comment: Switch to Android Studio

Comment: Have you test on device ?

Comment: Post your code with manifest

Comment: "Due to all these error my application is not initializing and see only black screen with 'Android' text in the middle of the screen of emulator"  It seems like you have a problem with emulator!!! not with the code.

Comment: You should install intel HAXM from sdk manager

Comment: goto sdk manager...and check ...have you installed system images???, and also check intel  HAXM, in extras folder in sdk manager.

Comment: Try to execute the apk file on you android phone, and then check whether the problem is with your apk file or emulator

Comment: If you are just starting with Android development you should switch to Android Studio because Android support for Eclipse is ending [soon](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html)

Comment: Meanwhile let me try the .apk on device

Comment: @Ankush yes please try it on your device... so that you may check whether the problem is in emulator

Comment: Thanks all guys.. I tried on device and worked well. As suggested by Greg I downloaded Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine, should work, the problem must be with the emulator.

PS: Also, I recommend using Android Studio for Android development. I recently started using it and makes everything so much easier.